# Using App_GlobalResources in other projects

Tags: .net, embedded-resource

I have a web site that has App_GlobalResources defining all the site's text values.  These are accessed in the views via strongly typed object (Resources.GlobalResource) and works great.

I've separated the controller into another project, but don't have access to the App_GlobalResources in the website, but need to (they've generated some controls in the controllers and need the localization there).

How can I best access the App_GlobalResources from another project?